# Crc ccitt (0x1d0f) calculating in C

Tags: c, crc, calculation

I have an array of values in hexadecimal.
I have pre-calculated CRC-CCITT (0x1d0f) of it which is : `0xD7F2`

I wrote an alghoritm based on working crc alghoritm wrote in javascript , which I tested with same entry of data ([calculation here](http://www.tahapaksu.com/crc/)).

I rewrote it inC, but unfortunatelly, I'm getting different output than expected, actually: `0xB5DB`.

So, my question is: is possible to have problem inside alghoritm? Could wrong data types causing problem?

Here is an example with a simple array of size 2. Calculated result by calculator is 0x9770, Result of my alghoritm is 0x5D80.

Calculation alghorithm:

```
unsigned int crcTest[2] = {0xB6FE,0x8C4A};

int main (void){
    unsigned int crc = doCrc(crcTest,2);
    printf("Correct CRC16-CCITT is: 0x9770\n");
    printf("Calculated result func : 0x%X\n", crc);
    return 0;
}    

unsigned int doCrc(unsigned int *data, int size)
    {
        int i, j;
        unsigned int crc = 0x1d0f;
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++){
            unsigned int xr = data[i] << 8;
            crc = crc^xr;

            for (j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            {
                if (crc & 0x8000){
                    crc = (crc << 1);
                    crc = crc ^ 0x1021;
                }
                else{
                    crc = crc << 1;
                }
            }
        }
        crc = crc & 0xFFFF;
        return crc;
    }
```

Whole source code main.c : [Download here](http://leteckaposta.cz/uploaded/954326008)

JavaScript code which actually works :

```
CRC1D0F: function() {
        var str = this.CleanedString;
        var crc = 0x1d0f;
        for (var c = 0; c < str.length; c++) {
            crc ^= str.charCodeAt(c) << 8;
            for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                if (crc & 0x8000)
                    crc = (crc << 1) ^ 0x1021;
                else
                    crc = crc << 1;
            }
        }
        return crc & 0xFFFF;
```

Comment: Please include your code (preferably as a [mcve]) directly in your question.

Comment: code has 2150 lines (array is tooooo long) so, do you really want that ?

Comment: do you really want us to find a bug in a code with 2150 lines?

Comment: array is too long (2050 lines)...alghorhitm is 15 lines maybe...
I posted file here , so you can try it with exactly same values...

Comment: Include some __minimal__ data as well as expected and actual CRC

Comment: Can you provide the JS code?

Comment: Don't try to invent an oval wheel when round ones are around. [LammertBies site](https://www.lammertbies.nl/comm/info/crc-calculation.html) has different versions of CRC, an online calculator to identify yours and a bunch of optimized and tested C routines.

Comment: If I remember correctly 1d0f is rather the pre-calculated value of 1021.

Comment: The problem I see is that your inner loop is written for 8-bit characters but your data is chunked in (probably 32-bit) unsigned integer, and *then* it looks like you want each input integer to be treated as a 16-bit value.  CRC operates on a string of bits, not bytes or words, and it's not clear what your intended bit stream is.

Comment: @MikeHousky what do you mean by 32-bit unsigned integer ? When i tried to get size of element in array, console printed 4 bytes. Whole size of array is 4 bytes * number of elements.  So you want to tell me that my inner loop is wrong, and i'm geting input from array wrong ?

Comment: @majkx00 could you a [mcve] in javascript that computes the CRC of `{0xB6FE,0x8C4A};` yielding `0x9770`? Add what is your input on the [online calculator](http://www.tahapaksu.com/crc/) that yields `0x9770`?

Comment: @Jabberwocky my source code for calculator in JavaScript is from exactly same page as you posted. Input that yields `0x9770` is `B6FE 8C4A`

Comment: @majkx00 OK, now I understand. You need this: `unsigned char data[] = "B6FE8C4A";` in the C code below.

Comment: So, i need to get whole content of an array, and merge it into one char ?

Comment: @majkx00 What I'm telling you is that computer memory is organized in bytes and words, while the CRC is a computation of a stream of bits.  You have modified a function that acts on an array of chars, interpreting each char in the as representing 8 bits from the stream.  The nested loops represent that organization, with each iteration of the outer loop processing one char, and each iteration of the inner loop processing one bit of the current char.  (There's an optimization that partially obscures this, doing an XOR of the whole char into the CRC value, but that's what's going on.)

Comment: @majkx00 So, if you have more than 8 bits per array entry, you need to change the inner loop to repeat for the correct number of bits, _and_ you need to change or remove that optimization.  All in all, I'd say you're better off building a char[] array with the bytes you want to compute the CRC of and passing that to the original char[] version of the function.

Comment: @MikeHousky hmm i tried to do the following : i have an arrray of unsigned int's as it was defined. Next, i'm calling function doCrc as follows : 
`unsigned int crc = (unsigned int)doCrc((unsigned char*)crcSrc,0x7FFE);`
Is this right way to do it ? I mean, you said i should build a char[] array and pass it to original char[] version of the function. I have original char[] function, i just want to make a conversion from unsigned int array type to char type.

Comment: @majkx00 The problem is that each int is more than one char and (should) contribute more than 8 bits to the CRC. All of your int constants are 4-digit hexadecimal, suggesting that you have 16 bits of interest (two bytes) of interest in each int.  However, each int on a typical implementation is more likely to be 32 bits.  Try including `<inttypes.h>` and using `uint16_t` as your data type.  If you don't have C99 support, try `unsigned short` instead.  pass the length as _twice_ the length of the `uint16_t` array, and cast the pointer to `(char*)`.

Comment: That will get you a CRC in whatever "endian" byte order your processor uses; which is almost always low byte first ("little endian") these days. But, it's your application and you need to figure out how many bytes there are and what order they are in.  One thing bears repeating: There is no such thing as a "hexadecimal type" in C.  That's only a notation for making the bits in an int, char, short, etc. value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is almost correct:

It should be:

```
unsigned int doCrc(unsigned char *data, int size)
```

instead of:

```
unsigned int doCrc(unsigned int *data, int size)
```

This works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

unsigned int doCrc(unsigned char *data, int size)
{
  int i, j;
  unsigned int crc = 0x1d0f;
  for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    unsigned int xr = data[i] << 8;
    crc = crc ^ xr;

    for (j = 0; j < 8; j++)
    {
      if (crc & 0x8000) {
        crc = (crc << 1);
        crc = crc ^ 0x1021;
      }
      else {
        crc = crc << 1;
      }
    }
  }
  crc = crc & 0xFFFF;
  return crc;
}    

unsigned char data[] = "1234567890";

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  printf("%0x\n", doCrc(data, strlen(data)));
}
```

Expected output:

```
57d8
```

which is the same as we get [here](http://www.tahapaksu.com/crc/).

Comment: with entry "1234567890" works perfect. But i have 32 766 entries in HEXadecimal, so i need solution for this

Comment: @majkx00 The problem is most likely within your data. You are computing the CRC of an array of __bytes__. Your testdata is specified as an array of `unsigned int`. Depending on the endianness and the size of `int` on your platform, the array of bytes seen by the `doCrc` function can be `{0xB6, 0xFE, , 0x80, 0x62, ...}`, `{0xFE, 0xB6, , 0x62, 0x80, ...}`, `{0xFE, 0xB6, 0x00, 0x00, 0x62, 0x80, 0x00, 0x00} etc.`

Comment: @ryyker , i'm sorry but i don't understand you. This alghorithm which Jabberwocky posted i'm not able to run due to type mismatch. Array is type of unsigned int , and parameter is unsigned char. When i try to post  unsigned int array to parameter of type unsigned char, i got a conversion error.

Comment: @majkx00 CRC16 isn't very suitable for 32766 "entries" (bytes?). You should be using CRC32.

Comment: @majkx00 You can safely cast from any pointer type to `unsigned char*` (the other way around is unsafe). Simply do `unsigned char* ptr = (unsigned char*)array;`.

Comment: @majkx00 please show us what CRC you expect for `unsigned int crcSrc[2] = {0xB6FE, 0x8062};`

Comment: @Jabberwocky so you telling me i need to converse type of array ? I tried it also with uint16_t , but same result. I also debugged alghoritm , where i printed readed entry , and values has been like : B6FE, 8062...etc.

Expected result for unsigned int crcSrc[2] = {0xB6FE, 0x8062}; is : 0x9770

Comment: @majkx00 please answer my previous comment.

Comment: expected result for unsigned int crcSrc[2] = {0xB6FE, 0x8062}; is 0x9770

Comment: @Lundin i tried to cast unsigned char* ptr = (unsigned char*)array; , but result is still different (even i used Jabberwocky alghorithm) , i got 0xBD8D instead of  0xD7F2

Comment: @majkx00 be aware that `"1234567890"` is the same as `{ 0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x34, 0x35, 0x36, 0x37, 0x38, 0x39, 0x30, 0 }`

Comment: @majkx00 Which is it?  You have 0xB6FE,0x8C4A in your code, but 0xB6FE,0x8062 in your comments here.  Which is supposed to get that CRC of 0x9770?